# How to get roles which have permissions on a particular page in kentico

Tags: kentico

i have a page(say TestPage), two roles(say Role1, Role2 ) are given permission on this page, now i want to get the names of the assigned roles in code using API. how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using the following code

```
TreeProvider provider = new TreeProvider(MembershipContext.AuthenticatedUser);
CMS.DocumentEngine.TreeNode page = provider.SelectNodes().Path("/News").OnCurrentSite().FirstObject;
var dataQuery=AclItemInfoProvider.GetACLItemsAndOperators(page.NodeID);
foreach(DataRow dr in dataQuery.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    //here you can find the information about the roles, their IDs and Display Names etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want to achieve? What do you mean by 'in program'? You mean like using API? You can utilize

> DocumentSecurityHelper

for working with permissions for a user for a certain page. You can find various examples for working with the ACL and permissions via API [here](https://docs.kentico.com/api9/content-management/page-security).

Comment: Yes i want to get the role names using API.I have tried using ACLItemInfoProvider.GetAclItems(page,adminuser), but it doesn't return any row in datatable.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Setting page permissions for a role](https://docs.kentico.com/api9/content-management/page-security#Pagesecurity-Settingpagepermissionsforarole). It should give you an idea how to do it. I guess you can use in your case:

`AclItemInfoProvider.GetAllowedRoles`